# Convert latex to rst/sphinx

Tags: latex, restructuredtext

I am writing documentation of a project using rst and sphinx. But earlier, I already wrote a part of it in latex and now want to convert it to rst to add it to the documentation. Converison of rst to latex is obvious, but a google search about the other way around didn't yield something directly.

So my question: Is there a way to convert latex to rst?

**Edit**
Ideally I would like to convert it to rST specifically for usage with sphinx. So it would be nice if it could use eg the extension of sphinx for displaying math.

Comment: The usual problem with converting LaTeX to Foo is that TeX is Turing complete, which means that LaTeX can not only describe any layout, but can do so in any number of different ways. If you are targeting a well defined subset of LaTeX it would be helpful to say so.

Comment: @dmckee: What do you mean with 'a well defined subset of LaTeX'? I'm just using latex, with some packages for math like amsmath

Comment: "Just using latex" means that you are using a Turing complete language, and the user (if sufficiently insane) can do *any* kind of programming they want with it, a fact which makes general conversions difficult. I suspect you are thinking of just using the kinds of macros which a appear in the Not So Short Introduction or some similar document, and that should be manageable.

Answer (score 10):

Try [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Comment: Pandoc seems nice! But I tried it, and the equations were not well converted (gave an error with converting the rst to html), tables were not well formatted, references of citations were not converted (but maybe there also some features specific to sphinx that are not genereal rst?)